# griddata generating data outside desired areas

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I am trying to interpolate data between points as shown in this 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqXVK.jpg). When I use the griddata function matlab, the interpolated data exceeds the boundary of the original data. The area of desired interpolation is highlighted by the boundary made in the figure. Is there any way around to this problem?

My code for interpolation an display

```
figure2 = figure;
[x , y] = meshgrid(min(Matrixmin(:,5)):0.01:max(Matrixmin(:,5)),min(Matrixmin(:,6)):0.01:max(Matrixmin(:,6)));%graduation des x et y.
[xi,yi,zi]=griddata(Matrixmin(:,5),Matrixmin(:,6),Matrixmin(:,10),x,y);
contourf(xi,yi,zi,'edgecolor','none','LevelStep',0.01);
h=colorbar('location','Eastout');colormap('jet');
```

I have also tried the interp2 function but the results are still the same.

Comment: How do you define that area you outlined? `griddata` uses the convex hull of the data points. If you want to cut out a smaller region, you need to somehow define that. Maybe look into alpha shapes.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating query points `[x, y]` using `meshgrid` that are outside the boundary of your image. Then, `griddata` is estimating the `zi` values at those query points. Behavior of both `meshgrid` and `griddata` is as expected. If you do not want points outside the boundary of the image, use the [inpolygon](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inpolygon.html) function to remove those points after creating`meshgrid`.